# Find and replace direct video link PHP

Tags: php, html

Is it possible to find and replace a direct video link with PHP? I keep trying to use str_replace to find the link and replace it with an already specified one.

But is just leaves the text blank without the link there or anything. 
Then it becomes `<source src="">` With nothing inside of the src

INDEX.HTML (Video thing)

```
<source src="@@LINK@@">
```

INDEX.PHP

```
  <?php


  $title = htmlspecialchars($_POST['title']);
  $link = htmlspecialchars($_POST['link']);
  $desc = htmlspecialchars($_POST['desc']);
  $pgname = htmlspecialchars($_POST['pagename']);


  copy('index.html', $pgname . '.html');

  $myFile = $pgname . '.html';

  $ch = curl_init($myFile);
  $output = curl_exec($ch);


  $data = file_get_contents($myFile);



  $replaceables = array("@@TITLE@@", "@@PGNAME@@", "@@DESC@@", "@@LINK@@");

  $new = array($title, $pgname, $desc, $link);

  $data = str_replace($replaceables, $new, $data);



  file_put_contents($myFile, $data);







  ?>
```

Comment: this code works fine for me. post your html that contains the `form` to ensure that the `$_POST` variable is getting populated correctly.